# What does (1) mean in terminal commands?

Tags: terminal, command

There are many commands that are labelled with a (1) such as rm(1) or ls(1). I am wondering what the (1) refers to, because it is not required when the command is entered.

I have tried looking it up, and found things referring to 1 as stdout and 2 referring to stderr. I don't think these are related, but I can't be certain. It wouldn't make sense with commands such as rm(1) since basic removal does not output in terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the "[section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections)" in which this man page is found.

1. General commands
2. System calls
3. Library functions, covering in particular the C standard library
4. Special files (usually devices, those found in /dev) and drivers
5. File formats and conventions
6. Games and screensavers
7. Miscellanea
8. System administration commands and daemons

And no, this is not related to the numbering of a process' file handles (such as 1 for stdout, 2 for stderr).

Answer (score 1):

When you see commands with numbers in parentheses, it's usually referring to the manual for that particular command.

If you go to a terminal window and type: `man rm` it will pull up the manual for that command and the top you'll see `rm(1)` or `ls(1)`.

The (1) (or whatever number) is just the section that it's in in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

It means the section which the man page is found. If you want you can view all man pages this way:

```
$ man -k .
__clone2 (2)         - create a child process
__fbufsize (3)       - interfaces to stdio FILE structure
__flbf (3)           - interfaces to stdio FILE structure
__fpending (3)       - interfaces to stdio FILE structure
...
```

And you can see that every command is part of a [specific section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections).